# jquery ajax, only one label per post returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

### http://jsfiddle.net/Pd2cp/2/

as in the jsFiddle above you'll see only one label is returned per post when there are many.
i am using the below jquery. how can i return ALL labels for EACH post. and just as [reference i got alot of info from here](http://www.threelas.com/2012/02/basic-blogger-json-feed-api.html)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2814965631975331659/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=8',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){
        var title = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
        for(var j = 0; j < data.feed.entry[i].category.length; j++){
        var categories = data.feed.entry[i].category[j].term;
        }
        $('#blogContainer').append(title+'<br/>'+categories+'<br/><br/>');
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Why are you using JSONP? You're not using a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop that goes through the categories, you were assigning the category values to the same variable `var category`, where it gets overwritten in every loop. What you need to do is have a `category` array that collects the category labels.

Here's the working code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2814965631975331659/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=8',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){
            var title = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
            var categories = []; // collect categories here
            for(var j = 0; j < data.feed.entry[i].category.length; j++){
                categories.push(data.feed.entry[i].category[j].term); // append the label to the category collection
            }
        $('#blogContainer').append(title+'<br/>'+ categories.join(', ') +'<br/><br/>');
        }
    }
});​
```